# Is there a memory-wise point to delete used functions or variables in JS?

Tags: javascript

I know, it's pretty far away from real world and syntax becomes less readable, but:

```
> let fn = {};
> fn[0] = () => {
... console.log(`some work is done`);
... delete fn[0];
... };
[Function]
> fn[0]();
some work is done
undefined
> fn
{}
```

So, it deletes the function after its return. Is there any theoretical point to do it? Does it free up the memory or something? Thanks.

Edit: '0' could be some actual name of the function, so `fn` object could be a place to keep all the declared variables, preventing them floating around. However, it's not the point.

Comment: The `delete` operator in itself incurs a performance regression, so avoid it when you don't need to really alter the shape of your objects.

Comment: If you know the function will only be used once, why not use an IIFE? Having the function delete itself from the container seems a bit questionable, because then any place that might call it has to test for its existence.

Comment: What's the point of the `fn` object? What other values will it contain? What will happen to it after `0` was called? Only with that information we can really answer the question.

Comment: @nnnnnn An IIFE is called immediately, but one might want to delay the call. I've used a similar pattern before for lazy evaluating, nullifying the thunk function when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Assign the function to a local variable with `let`. When the scope ends, the function will go away.

Comment: @Bergi, I've updated the question to explain the purpose of `fn` object here. However, thanks for letting me know about the `delete` operator.

Comment: @JulyMorning "*fn object could be a place to keep all the declared variables*" - I don't get that. Variables are not part of an object, properties are. Preventing variables from floating around is the purpose of scopes. Sure the name isn't important, but why do you want to store it on an object? How would the code look like if you didn't? Where would the variable "float" to?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the function temporarily, you can assign it to a block-scope variable with `let`.

```
{
    let fn = () => { some code };
    do stuff here
    fn();
    do more stuff here
}
```

Comment: Or you could just create a IIFE `(() => { console.log('hello world') })()`